# Bash script to SSH to multiple servers and continue if login failed

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a Bash script that uses SSH keys to login to a list of servers.

The script iterates over a flat text file of hostnames called test_hosts.txt.

The script works fine except if one of the logins fails for some reason. If a login fails on one of the hosts, the entire script stops and none of the other hosts on the list are logged into.

How can I adjust this script to keep going if the login fails for any reason?

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="username@domain@"

KPATH="/path/to/key"

while read host; do
    echo $host
    echo ${KPATH}    

    GETSIZE="df -h"
    ssh ${USER}$host ${KPATH} "${GETSIZE}" > Test/Hosts/$host.txt

done <Test/Hosts/test_hosts.txt
```

UPDATE: The script stops meaning, it does not continue on to the next host on the list.

Comment: What do you mean the script stops, it hangs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, but `ssh` tends to read from standard input, and try to pass whatever it finds there to the remote computer. When you use `ssh` in a `while read` loop, this can mean that `ssh` will steal the data you intended to `read` in the loop. If this is the problem, there's a fairly simple solution: pass the host file over fd 3 instead of standard input:

```
while read -u3 host; do
    ...
done 3<Test/Hosts/test_hosts.txt
```

(The `3<` opens the file on fd 3 instead of stdin, and `-u3` tells `read` to read from fd 3.)

Another possibility is to add the `-n` option to `ssh`, which tells it not to read from stdin.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting this error when trying that adjustment: 7: read: Illegal option -u

Comment: @pengz: Apparently, your shell's `read` builtin doesn't support `-u`; in that case, you can use `read host <3` instead. (Or just stick with `ssh -n` if that's doing what you need.)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the program `clusterssh` (`cssh`). It seems to be more fitting for your needs than custom script. Just insert in its configuration file your server names and other information.
http://manpages.org/cssh